# post data to controller from view using viewModel classes -ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working ASP.NET MVC-5 app. I got form in Razor partial View and it require multiple models so i use ViewModel; putting all classes (models) reference in that as following

```
public class QualificationViewModel
{    
    public Qualification _Qualification;

    //public Subject _Subject;

    //public FeeScheme _FeeScheme;

}
```

now for time-being i am using only qualification model just to test my code but i am failing to send data from view to controller method. I am getting null value in debug in controller method

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateNewQualification()
    {
        return PartialView("PartialQualification_Create");

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateNewQualification(QualificationViewModel newQualificationData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //code here...
            }
        }
        catch (DataException ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable To Create New Qualification!" + ex);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("QualificationHome");
    }
```

I am using jQuery Ajax method to post the data, with similar way i have succeeded of sending data for single model class....

```
function submit_createNewQualification()
{      
    alert(JSON.stringify($("#NewQualificationForm").serializeObject()));

    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/Qualification/CreateNewQualification",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ newQualificationData: $("#NewQualificationForm").serializeObject() }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == true) {
                window.location = "/Qualification/QualificationHome";
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        }
    });

}
```

and i have following form in view...

```
 @model DatabaseLayer.ViewModels.QualificationViewModel

  @using (Html.BeginForm("CreateNewQualification", "Qualification", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "NewQualificationForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
           <div class="col-md-6">
             @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle)
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Qualification.QualificationTitle)
           </div>
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Qualification.Active, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
             <div class="col-md-6 custom-checkBox-block-1">
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Qualification.Active)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Qualification.Active)
              </div>
           </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
             <input type="submit" value="Create Qualification" onclick="submit_createNewQualification()"  class="btn btn-default" />
         </div>
       </div>
}
```

many thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
public class QualificationViewModel
{    
   public Qualification _Qualification {get; set;}

//public Subject _Subject;

//public FeeScheme _FeeScheme;

}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateNewQualification()
{
    var Model = new QualificationViewModel();
    return PartialView("PartialQualification_Create",model);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to JSON stringify your model, you just simply send a serialized version of your form, default MVC model binding will handle the rest:

```
data: $("#NewQualificationForm").serialize()
```

Comment: ok i try in a minute as you said ... but test code with single model and it works... my issue i believe is in ViewModel!!!